# translate a vector by another vector

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

let $T_A:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$, and $A$ is vector in $\mathbb R^n$ such that  $$T_A(X)=X+A$$
$T_A$ is called the translation by $A$, but I don't understand why we call this mapping a translation, because if you add a vector $X$ to another vector $A$ you will get a new vector, not the translation of $A$, if $X+A$ is the translation of $X$ then we get that $$\mid \mid X+A\mid \mid = \mid \mid X \mid \mid$$
Which is not true unless $A=O$.

In this picture, let $A=(1,1)$ and $X=(5,2)$, and you can see the diffrence between adding the vector $X+A=C$ and translating $X$ by $A$

[image]

Comment: You need to move the tail with it.

Comment: Who says that $\|X\|$ should be the same thing as $\|T_A(X)\|$?

Comment: Translation means moving by definition.

Comment: You may be confusing yourself with the property that $X-Y = T_A(X)-T_A(Y)$ and so the distance between points $X$ and $Y$ is the same as the distance between the translation of $X$ **and the translation of $Y$**.  Of course translating $X$ and not translating $Y$ the distance can change.

Comment: @JMoravitz can you see the pictrue

Comment: Yes I see it, you have the grey line which should have been $X$ in your example mislabeled.  What about it?  The tip of the **vector** $C$ (*with tail at the origin*) is the same as the tip of the **ray** $B$ (*with tail at $(1,1)$*).  What is your issue with it?  The tip is what is important here, not the rest.

Comment: We understand vector as an element of vector space. From that point of view $B=A$. You probably think of translation of an element from tangent space $T_XM$, where $M$ is the plane. But it's not the same as the translation of a vector

Comment: Now... if we were to take the collection of points in the plane which forms the line segment that you see pictured, $X_\ell=\{t\cdot (5,2)~:~0\leq t\leq 1\}$, and we look at the collection of points $\{T_A(x)~:~x\in X_\ell\}$ that collection of points is going to be graphically identical to the line segment pictured for $B$.  You are focusing on only translating the tip of the arrow and not translating any of the rest of the arrow and thinking it looks wrong.  Translate the entire arrow like you should and you'll have what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing two ways of thinking about a "vector". One is that it's an arrow starting at the origin. The other is that it's just an $n$-tuple of coordinates - that is, a point in $n$-space.

The map you describe translates points in space, each the same way determined by $A$. In your picture that's diagonally up and right by a distance $\sqrt{2}$.

It's often useful (particularly in physics) to think of a vector as an arrow. It's just not right in this context.

Comment: I understand you want to keep the answer simple, but I think you cannot avoid mentioning that $n$-tuples (points) are *not* vectors, in the strict sense that they are not given a structure of linear space, leading to the definition of affine space instead.

Comment: @Miguel $n$-tuples of reals have addition and scalar multiplication - with those operations they are a vector space. Real Euclidean $n$-space (a geometric object) is just affine until you choose an origin.

Answer (score 0):

Think of $X$ as a point in space. Then $X + A$ is precisely the result of translating $X$ by $A$ (thought of as a vector in the sense that you are thinking of them).